# SQL select from all from table that are not in other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to select all users that their user id is not in another table.

Users table (user id is `user_id`)

Ghosts table (user id is `id`)

this is what I got so far:

```
$sql = "select * from users where users.user_id <> ghosts.id;";
```

Please advise...

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NOT IN:

```
select * from users u where u.user_id not in (select id from ghosts);
```

or NOT EXISTS:

```
select *
  from users u
 where not exists (select 1 from ghosts g where g.id = u.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may also work, although I like Brian's answer.

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN ghosts g
ON u.user_id = g.id
WHERE g.id IS NULL
```